# Wordpress hook - Execute code after adding a new tag

Tags: wordpress, tags, hook

i want to execute some code after the admin has created a new 
tag* but i can not find the hook.

*http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag

i found this [hook list](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook) but when i search for "add_tag" i get only this

```
add_tag_form
add_tag_form_fields
add_tag_form_pre
```

Can someone tell me the correct hook?

```
add_action('XXXX','triggerAfterAddNewTag');
function triggerAfterAddNewTag()
{
   echo $newTagId;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the `create_term` hook:

```
function my_create_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ){
  // $term_id is the term id
  // $tt_id is the term taxonomy id
  // $taxonomy is the taxonomy slug
}
add_action( 'create_term', 'my_create_term', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Best choice is `created_post_tag` or `created_term` hooks.

**Actions for terms of any taxonomy:**

```
do_action( 'create_term',  $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
do_action( 'created_term', $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
do_action( 'edited_term',  $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );
do_action( 'delete_term',  $term,    $tt_id, $taxonomy, $deleted_term, $object_ids );
```

And hooks for them:

```
add_action( 'create_term',  'wpse_create_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'created_term', 'wpse_created_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'edited_term',  'wpse_edited_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'delete_term',  'wpse_delete_term', 10, 5 );
```

Example:

```
/**
 * @param int      $term_id    Term ID
 * @param int      $tt_id       Taxonomy ID
 * @param string   $taxonomy    Taxonomy Slug
 */
function wpse_updated_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy ) {
  if ( $taxonomy == 'post_tag' ) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

From documentaion:

[create_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_term/) — Fires immediately after a new term is created, before the term cache is cleaned.

[created_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_term/) — Fires after a new term is created, and after the term cache has been cleaned.

[edited_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_term/) — Fires after a term has been updated, and the term cache has been cleaned.

[deleted_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_term/) — Fires immediately after an object-term relationship is deleted.

**Special actions for `post_tag` taxonomy terms:**

```
do_action( 'create_post_tag',  $term_id, $tt_id);
do_action( 'created_post_tag', $term_id, $tt_id);
do_action( 'edited_post_tag',  $term_id, $tt_id);
do_action( 'delete_post_tag',  $term,    $tt_id, $deleted_term, $object_ids );
```

Hooks and example:

```
add_action( 'created_post_tag', 'wpse_updated_post_tag', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edited_post_tag',  'wpse_updated_post_tag', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'delete_post_tag',  'wpse_updated_post_tag', 10, 4 );

/**
 * @param int      $term_id    Term ID
 * @param int      $tt_id       Taxonomy ID
 */
function wpse_updated_post_tag( $term_id, $tt_id) {
    // do something
}
```